# Angular.js filter across a factory through ng-options ng-model code review

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory, angular-filters, angularjs-ng-options

*Note that the following works, but it feels really clunky. I am looking for any tips in making it tighter and or gotchas which I may regret later.*

Flattened array of nested objects:

```
$scope.parents = 
  [
    {"name":"parent 1", "id":"1",
        "children":  [
            {"name":"child 1a", "id":"1a", "parentid":"1"}, {"name":"child 1b", "id":"1b", "parentid":"1"}
        ]
    },
    {"name":"parent 2", "id":"2",
        "children":  [
            {"name":"child 2a", "id":"2a", "parentid":"2"}, {"name":"child 2b", "id":"2b", "parentid":"2"}
        ]
    }
  ];
```

needs to be populated in two `<select>` objects, one for parents one for children, and their hierarchical relationship maintained. So that, when a parent is selected, children which are not underneath it are filtered out:

```
ng-options="item.id for item in children | filter:{'id':  data.parents.id}"
```

as well as when a child is selected, the parent is automatically recognized across the model

```
 $scope.parents = $filter('filter')($scope.parents, {id: $scope.data.children.parentid});
```

I feel as if I am missing something.

---

#### http://jsfiddle.net/petarsubotic/65kwvnjz/11/

Comment: This seems to be a very bad idea. The best you can  do is to `$watch` the parents and children and populate the arrays depending on what you want to achieve. Acceptance criteria seem to be totally random to me.